# How to pass data from onSuccess to other class?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-async-http

I am developing one app and it is based on json. I want to pass data form one class to other class which is received in onSuccess method. when i request for data then data will be receive properly but when i call that data to other class the null pointer error will occur.
my method is

```
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params1) {

            RequestParams params;
            params = new RequestParams();
            params.add("username", str_emailId);
            params.add("password", str_password);
            params.add("action", action);

            String str_result=constant.login(params);

            Log.d("Result::--",str_result);

            return null;
        }
```

and my login method is

```
public String login( RequestParams params1) {

        client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.post(Constant.check_login_user, params1, new TextHttpResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int i, Header[] headers, String response) {

                str_result = response;
                Log.d("Str_Result: ", str_result);

           }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String response, Throwable e) {
                if (statusCode == 401) {
                    jsonString[0] = response;
                    Log.d("onFailure: ", jsonString[0]);
                }
            }

        });

        return str_result;
    }
```

i got the data in on Success method and it will print in log ok but when return the str_result variable it will return null and i print the log in doInBackground() method it will return null pointer error i don't know how? please any one can help me that how to print that data thanks in advance.

Comment: Its because you are using async http client. you return value from the function before onSuccess fires up.

Comment: i don't know more about async http client so is there any way to pass data from onSuccess() method to doInBackground() method

Answer (score 1):

You can post your models to all alive fragments or activites with EventBus.

Link: https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Answer (score 0):

Your POST method is Asynchronous function. For simplicity, imagine it starts doing it's work in the background, while rest of application continues doing whatever it's doing. When POST method is finished, it will call onSuccess() method or onFailure() method, depending whether POST method succeeded or failed. You see, you call the POST method and return result right away even though POST method didn't finish. You can imagine your login method doing something like this.

1. result = null
2. call login()
3. return result
4. login is finished and calls onSuccess()

So you see, you return result before login method finished executing.

How to fix it?

Class that receives String result should implement function like:
`public void setResult(String result) {...}`

and your login method should call it in onSuccess() method like this:

```
@Override
public void onSuccess(int i, Header[] headers, String response) {
  // Your login method finished, now you can send result to receiving object
  str_result = response;
  receivingClassObject.setResult(str_result);
}
```

Comment: i do what you say but it will send me an error like can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper .preper()

Comment: That is completely different set of problems. I suggest you start reading http://developer.android.com/about/start.html